# Append a 1d array to a 2d array in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a numpy 2D array `[[1,2,3]]`.
I need to append a numpy 1D array,( say `[4,5,6]`) to it, so that it becomes `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`

This is easily possible using lists, where you just call *append* on the 2D list.

But how do you do it in Numpy arrays?

`np.concatenate` and `np.append` dont work. they convert the array to 1D for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: `vstack` does `np.concatenate([np.atleast_2d(m) for m in tup], 0)` - in other words - make sure all inputs are 2d and then concatenate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want *[vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack)*:

```
In [45]: a = np.array([[1,2,3]])

In [46]: l = [4,5,6]

In [47]: np.vstack([a,l])
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

You can stack multiple rows on the condition that *The arrays must have the same shape along all but the first axis.*

```
In [53]: np.vstack([a,[[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]])
Out[53]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: it doesn't work similarly with hstack though... col_vector_to_append = np.column_stack([4, 5, 6]).T is needed

Comment: @Mehdi surely vstack is the transposed version of hstack right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
np.concatenate(([a],[b]),axis=0)
```

when

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
```

then result should be:

> array([[1, 2, 3],
>          [4, 5, 6]])